# regex replace text in line with multiple tags if the word is in the external txt file in python

Tags: python, regex, text, replace, line

i have many lines like this line (please scroll to read whole line):

```
 <br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; 3 Point Updated<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Shape Removed 4<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Point 3 Added<br>
```

I need to remove from every line begining from 
....Point....
  where inside those tags will find words listed in the external txt file (like for example word "Point")

my code is now:

```
with open(input.txt') as input:
    lines=input.readlines()
    with open(output.txt', "w") as output:
        for line in lines:
            if "Point" in line:
                output.write(re.sub('(<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp;.*?)Point(.*?<br>)', '<br>', line, flags=re.DOTALL))
            else:
                output.write(line)
```

when im using this code its only deleting once if it finds "Point" in line and leaves:

```
<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Shape Removed 4<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Point 3 Added<br>
```

How to make replace multiply instances between 
 tags of Point word?

And second question: Right now im only using `if "Point" in line` but it would be great if it would search for the words loading from the external txt file.
Thanks for help!

Comment: i should writee on the beggining: I need to remove from every line begining from
<br>....Point....<br>
where inside those tags will find words listed in the external txt file (like for example word "Point")

Comment: Please provide an example of what the line **should** look like when your code is correct. Also, you can edit your own question, instead of providing additional information in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the result you want, let me know if it needs to be modified:

```
bad_words = []
with open('bad_words.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        bad_words.append(line.rstrip())

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
        for line in f:
            kept_parts = []
            for chunk in line.split("<br>"):
                if all(bad_word not in chunk for bad_word in bad_words) :
                    kept_parts.append(chunk)

            line = "<br>".join(kept_parts)

            output.write(line + "\n")
```

Result:

```
<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Shape Removed 4<br>
```

In essence, you don't need regex. Just split the code into lines (`<br>` denotes a line); ignore any chunks that contain the undesired text; and rejoin the resulting list.

Comment: Thanks Darkstarone. This works. I didnt thought about using line.split. Thanks. If I have other words like Point in external txt file one under another how should i loop this to find other words as well and replace them?

Comment: So is the text file with all the words you want to replace separate from `'input.txt'`? Or is it part of it?

Comment: its different txt file

Comment: Updated to get all the words from `'bad_words.txt'`, and added an `all` iterative if condition to check all words aren't in a line.